# How to detect multiple browser's tabs open in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I would like to ask about How to detect multiple browser's tabs open in Vuejs?

I found this implement but it is in jQuery
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/check-duplicate-browser-tab-window/

example:

1. open tab 1: open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
2. open tab 2: open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) (will alert/detect [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) is already opened)

Appreciate for helping.
Thank you

Comment: Track it using sessionStorage https://forum.vuejs.org/t/i-need-to-detect-tab-close-and-browser-close-event/72537/7